# Grub 2 install error: grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am trying to install grub2 from a live CD of lubuntu 16.04, I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajs9rO5upZA), after I mounted the `/dev/sda1` in the mnt folder using this commands

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

Then changing the root directory :

```
    sudo chroot /mnt
```

But when try installing grub using `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` I get this error :

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist.   Please specify --target or --directory.
```

I tried turning off the uefi mode from bios but I think that my bios version doesn't even support it because it is from 2005

Answer (score 8):

Dont know if you solved your problem, thus this is 1y ago.

I ran into a same situation recently in Ubuntu 18.04, that chroot to another directory and run grub-install:

```
$ chroot /media/cdrom0 grub-install
```

Throws error:

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

Finally solved this error by installing grub-pc:

```
$ sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

After this, items under /usr/lib/grub changed from:

```
grub-mkconfig_lib  x86_64-efi  x86_64-efi_signed
```

To:

```
grub-mkconfig_lib  i386-pc  x86_64-efi
```

Comment: works like a charm !

Comment: Thanks! Installing `grub-pc` helped me for same kind of problem while using woeusb

Answer (score 5):

install `grub-pc-bin`

<s>`grub-pc`</s>appears to be a meta package which will remove(!) `grub-efi-amd64`, which I guess would brick the pc, maybe not right away.

installing `apt install grub-pc-bin` added the necessary decencies for me to install pc bootloaders from an efi system.

Comment: For those who haphazardly installed `grub-pc`, like I did, and then saw that `apt` had removed `grub-efi-amd64` you can run two commands which will fix things: 1) `apt install grub-efi-amd64` and 2) `apt install grub-pc-bin`

Answer (score 2):

Just install Grub Customizer and you can do the rest easily by the following command:

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command first (in the live session):

```
sudo apt install grub-efi
```

then run the grub-install command again - this fixed the error for me

Tip from this comment: https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/#comments/350013